# Navigation dashboard pages is blocked React, RequireAuth, AuthenticationService, firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

good morning

I'm developing an application in react using firebase for authentication.

I have the RequireAuth component for the Routes where it is necessary to login, and in the AppRouter component it is as follows in the Routes
<Route element={ } path="my-profile" exact>

My problem is that the navigation between pages does not work on the dashboard and the application is completely blocked

In RequireAuth if I remove setLoaded(1); in AuthenticationService.observeStatus, the navigation between pages already works, but if the user is not logged in, it does not redirect to /login and the page is blank

Can you help me with this problem?

This is the code for the RequireAuth component

```
function RequireAuth({ children }) {
  const location = useLocation();

  const { logged } = useSelector((state) => state.authUserData);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(0);

  AuthenticationService.observeStatus(() => {
    setLoaded(1);
  });

  if (logged) return children;

  if (loaded)
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
}

export default RequireAuth;
```

`

I expect a solution to the problem I have in my app's navigation